# Minor edits are discouraged ? Under-editing?

Tags: discussion

Specifically referencing [From what age should one heed "But I'm not cold!"?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/24345/from-what-age-should-one-heed-but-im-not-cold?comment49452_24345)

User Ryan went to the effort to commend that "daughter days..." should read "daughter says..."

I made the edit, and lacking sufficient rep in this stack, the edit went to the review queue as per normal SE process.

The edit was accepted, but User DCShannon states in a comment "Putting a review in the queue with a single character change is discouraged."

The answer has been improved and clarified as a result of the tiny edit.   Stack Exchange is all about the question and the best answers rise.   Stating that a minor improvement-edit is discouraged is an excellent way to discourage participation in a stack.

Yes, one character is a really small change, but nothing else needed changing.

Are minor edits discouraged on Parenting.SE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ramificatons to minor edits. Speaking as a moderator, minor edits of that kind [are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) on SO sites because of many factors (pushing the post to the top of the active list, increasing the number of reviews in the queue, stalling more substantial reviews, overwhelming the limit on the number of edits one can approve or reject in a day, etc.) In general, if you can find a way to improve the rest of the post, that is a much better option (for example, there was another error which was corrected after your edit.)

Speaking as *a user*, I had no problem with that edit (I was the user who approved it.) Someone made a typo which might be potentially embarrassing to the OP, and you fixed it. I think that's fine. This site is not so busy that a small edit is a big burden. However, you will see this kind of negative feedback to very minor edits on most SO sites.

Minor edits are often rejected by reviewers. If you have enough edits rejected, the system will automatically place you on a brief edit ban.

For the "official" Stack Overflow policy on edits, see [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/262486)

Comment: An edit that minor could potentially be fixed with a comment, getting the OP to do it.